geopandas, extraction of xy from geometry results in integers
I have come by a workrelated problem.
I have a GeoDataFrame with geometry of POINTS. They are perfect with lots of decimals.
When i do a
df_kunde['utmx'], df_kunde['utmy'] = df_kunde.geometry.x, df_kunde.geometry.y
the resulting columns are integers. I have never experienced this before.
It was also a problem for me when converting SQL data to WKT. here i had to add a
.to_wkt(trim=False)
for it to give me integers.
It seems to me that it is bug in a module, but i cant find which. I am using
pandas 1.4.4
geopandas 0.12.2
These are old versions, but they are not the problem. It has worked before to give me floats and the issue is not solved by upgrading to newest version of them.
Has anyone else had this same problem?


Is there any reason you can't make a MRE so we can reproduce your problem?

Have you changed the precision of the geometries?
